# Translation algorithm - combinations to indices

Tags: algorithms, python

I have a deck of 52 poker cards represented as array of int - `[0, 1, ... 51]`.

There are 2.598.960 possible combinations of 5 cards. I can generate all combinations like this:

```
#id      #combination
0 -       0,  1,  2,  3,  4
1 -       0,  1,  2,  3,  5
2 -       0,  1,  2,  3,  6
   ...omitted data..
2598957 - 46, 47, 49, 50, 51
2598958 - 46, 48, 49, 50, 51
2598959 - 47, 48, 49, 50, 51
```

How I can effectively find `#id` for given `#combination` and `#combination` for given `#id`?

Comment: If you generate the list of all combinations, you now have a hash table. Given a set of cards, generate the same hash and do a lookup. The trick is a repeatable way of generating the hash number from a set of cards.

Comment: @gbjbaanb list or dictionary with indices already in place. I am looking for an algorithm.

Comment: If you have no way of calculating a particular row in the table from your cards then you'll just have to loop through them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first card you have 52 options for the second you have 51 and so on. You need to encode a sequence `c1`, `c2`, `c3`, `c4` and `c5` where there are 52, 51, 50 ,49, 48 options resp.

You can adjust the numbers by counting how many of the previous numbers are smaller: `a5 = c5 - sum(x < c5 for x in [c1, c2, c3, c4])`

you can simply encode it as a single integer  `output =(((a1*51 + a2)*50 + a3)*49 + a4)*48 + a5`.

you can extract it by using the modulo operation and integer divide.

```
int input = //...

a5 = input%48;
input/=48;
a4 = input%49;
input/=49;
a3 = input%50;
input/=50;
a2 = input%51;
input/=51;
a1 = input;
```

And then the reverse operation is needed to adjust them all back into the range `[0..52)`.

Comment: Thank you for great tip. I kind of stock with indexing 0,1,2.. Now I just realised that I don't need index. ints are just fine!

Comment: Or you could multiply by 100 and you'd have an id that you can read as well.

Comment: @Neil and then you don't have to adjust the individual cards either.

Comment: The only problem that I see in that is that it leaves spaces in your "id" range.

Comment: Technically there still is in my answer as it assumes that the order of the cards matter, if you remove that then you have a lot less options for the subsequent cards but the algorithm is more complicated.

Comment: @ratchetfreak It wasn't a criticism on your answer, just thought I'd add that comment.